# css footer not occupy the space and content not showed completely

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a footer by css and want the footer to be the bottom of page, however, some content are stretch to inside the footer, 
the following are my footer css

```
#footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}

<div id="footer" style="background-color:#0099CC">
    <center>
    <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">Copyright © 2016, Chaatz</td>
    <td align="right" style="white-space:pre"><a href="https://legal.html">Terms and Conditions</a>
                                              <a href="https://privacy.html">Privacy Notice</a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </center>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please explain more? What is wrong?

Comment: Maybe I think the bottom:0; made the div no height, thus the content in the page are being hide inside the div

Comment: I have added left:0 to the #footer and everything looks okay in here: https://jsfiddle.net/bemuf05u/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the height of the footer element as a padding-bottom of the content and negate the same value in margin-top of the footer element.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    page content
</div>

<div class="footer">
    footer content
</div>

.wrapper{
    height:100%;
    padding-bottom:150px;
}

.footer{
    height:150px;
    margin-top:-150px;
}
```